# Opening a webpage in a new TAB in OBIEE 11G

Tags: oracle11g, actionlink, obiee

I am working on Action Links in OBIEE11g where I am supposed to open a webpage in a new TAB from a report using Action Links. I am able to open the link in a new window but not in new tab. Is there any solution for this? Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Whether the browser opens a new tab or a new window often relates to how the browser is configured, and there's only so much the server/web page can do to influence that. I'm not aware of any fine-grained controls to affect that within OBI.